# Hadrons in realistic string phenomenology

Tags: string-theory, strong-force, phenomenology

String theory contains a number of models of baryons as branes, notably the Sakai-Sugimoto model. But I don't remember ever seeing a discussion of baryons, or any kind of hadron, in the specific context of standard model vacua. Yet it seems a natural question - whether and how one may import holographic models of mesons and baryons into realistic vacua. Can it be done, can it not be done? Is it a trivial generalization, is it non-trivial? I don't recall seeing even a remark about this.